# Handing custom HINSTANCE to MFC Dialog

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I am porting the GUI of a very old plugin from win32 to MFC. The dialog used to be started by invoking something like:

```
DialogBoxParam( GetDLLInstance(), ..., GetHWND(), ..., ... )
```

When trying to debug why my MFC solution doesn't work, I found, that above code would fail if I replace `GetDLLInstance()` by `nullptr`. So, for the code to work, it seems to be imperative, to provide it with the correct `HINSTANCE`, as the default one seems to be wrong. As MFC is just a wrapper for those win32 functions, I assume it also has to be provided with this information. However, when starting a `CDialogEx`-derived class, I didn't find a way to set a `HINSTANCE`. So how do I tell the MFC widgets the correct `HINSTANCE` for their internal call to `DialogBoxParam( ... )`?

Comment: use `AfxSetResourceHandle()` before rundialog

Comment: [Accessing the current module’s HINSTANCE from a static library](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20041025-00/?p=37483). As for MFC, see [Managing the State Data of MFC Modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/managing-the-state-data-of-mfc-modules).

Comment: Doesn't `GetDLLInstance()` work as it used to? If the "plugin" was a DLL before and is still a DLL it should work the same.  The `HINSTANCE` parameter in `DialogBoxParam()` is the module handle where the dialog resource is located. Try `AfxGetInstanceHandle()` or even `AfxFindResourceHandle()`. `DialogBoxParam()` is Win32 though. If you want an MFC-based dialog you should instead define a `CDialog`-based class and call `DoModal()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[AfxSetResourceHandle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/application-information-and-management?view=msvc-170#afxsetresourcehandle) sets the HINSTANCE handle that determines where the default resources of the application are loaded.
As @RbMm said, you need to set before rundialog and restore instantly.
For Modeless Dialog Box,

```
HMODULE hPrevious = AfxGetResourceHandle();
AfxSetResourceHandle(hMod);
CMyDialog *pDlg = new CMyDialog();
pDlg->Create(ID_DLG, this);
AfxSetResourceHandle(hPrevious);
pDlg->ShowWindows(SW_SHOW);
```

For Modal Dialog Box, see [the answer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/658036/how-to-include-rc-file-to-share-dialogs-from-one-p.html).